# Do children need to pay for residence permit in Denmark?

Tags: resident-permit, children, denmark

I cannot seem to find a definite information about this. I know that in Norway children do not need to pay, but is this the case in Denmark?

My family and I are non-EU nationals. My children were not born in Denmark. We are considering about moving to Denmark.

It seems from [here](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/fee/about_fees/overview-of-case-categories-and-fees.htm) that accompanying family members need to pay.

Comment: What's your citizenship and status? Was your child born in Denmark? It does not seem that residence permits are free for children *per se* but [fees are waived for family reunification](https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/fee/about_fees/about_fees.htm) and a few other cases that should cover most (or all?) children.

Comment: @Gala, what is the difference between accompanying family and family reunification?

Comment: I would guess that accompanying family is when people move together around the same time, family reunification is when one member of the family is a resident and he or she gets his spouse and children to join him or her later on (either because they initially stayed in another country or because they married after one of them moved to Denmark). But I don't know Danish law so that's just a guess.

Comment: Alternatively, this could also be a distinction between the family of third-country nationals and the family of Danish or EU citizens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children, regardless of age, count as accompanying family members and pay the same residence permit fee as other accompanying family members.

When applying for a residence permit, there are however additional fees that one must pay on top of the permit fee itself, and children under 18 are exempt for certain application categories.

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases in which the fee is waived, for example, for Turkish citizens.  Being a child does not seem to be, in and of itself, sufficient.

Source:

https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-us/coming_to_dk/fee/about_fees/